# Change the select option value based on input field

Tags: javascript, php, html

I really don't know how to do it. Is it possible to do this process?
I want to change the select option value based on the user input on the quant field

```
<input type="number" name="quant" id="quant" /> // for example I enter 2
<select name="shipment" disable>
 <option value="100"> 100 per 1 item </option>
 <option value="150"> 150 per 2 item </option> //this must be selected
</select>
```

My actual code in php

```
    <select name="shipment" id="">
<?php 
foreach($shipment as $num => $price)
{
    if($num != NULL || $price !=NULL)
    {
?>              
<option value="<?php echo "{$price}"?>">
    <?php echo "{$price}"." for "."{$num}"." item";?></option>
<?php 
    }
}
?>

</select>
<h4 style="padding:0px;margin:0px;float:left;margin-top:10px;"  class="col-md-3" >Quantity: </h4>
<div class="col-md-9" style="padding-left:0px;"><input  type="number"  name="quant" onblur="multiply.call(this,this.form.elements.price.value,this.form.elements.quant.value)"
 min="1" max="10" placeholder="2" style="height:2em;margin:3px;"></div>
```

I have to make a simple calculation this is the price of the item:

```
<h4 style="padding:0px;margin:0px;float:left;"  class="col-md-12" >Sale Price: ₱<font color='red'><?php $price= number_format(intval($shop_item_orig_price-($shop_item_orig_price*($shop_item_sale/100)))); echo $price;?> </font> </h4>
```

I will multiply it based on the quantity

```
    <input  type="number"  name="quant" onblur="multiply.call(this,this.form.elements.price.value,this.form.elements.quant.value);myFunction(this.value)"
 min="1" max="10" placeholder="2" style="height:2em;margin:3px;">
```

And then add the shipping fee based on the selected value.

Comment: What output you want ? Select dropdown value changes to what ?

Comment: And what does your PHP plays role here?

Comment: @NanaPartykar for example I enter 2 on my input field 
The select option value will be 150 for 2 item

if i enter 1 
The select option value will be 100 for 1 item

Comment: @divy3993 I just want to show my process now.

Comment: Can you show the html output of php code?

Comment: @jcubic the one above the php code...

Answer (score 2):

I am showing you the simple demo for your question below:

**UPDATE**

```js
function myFunction(quantValue)
{
  var shipmentOption = document.getElementById("shipmentSelect");
  shipmentOption.selectedIndex = quantValue - 1;
}
```

```html
<input  type="number" name="quant" placeholder="2" onblur="myFunction(this.value)"/>

<select name="shipment" id="shipmentSelect">
 <option value="100"> 100 per 1 item </option>
 <option value="150"> 150 per 2 item </option> //this must be selected
</select>
```

**Explanation:** The demo is with very simple logic of **`selectedIndex`**. So assuming that your entries would be **searialized options**. So if `1` is the **input** than select first option, `2` is the **input** select the second option,.... and so on.

**Second Update**:

[JSFiddle:Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/divy3993/b0d92ab5/)

Hope that it help you.

Comment: @JonasDulay Check the Update.

Comment: Check JavaScript selectedIndex in Script.

Comment: onblur="multiply.call(this,this.form.elements.price.value,this.form.elements.quant.value);myFunction(this.value)" I have this fuction on my quant field
it happens that my multiply.call is not working

Comment: what is `multiply.call(this,this.form.elements.price.value,this.form.elements.qua‌​nt.value)` doing? I mean what is it for?

Comment: I will multiply the price * quantity... now i have to add the value of the shipment select value... is there anyway i can do it ?
[code]<input id="total" name="answer" style="margin-top:10px;margin-left:5px;"readonly />

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102881/discussion-between-divy3993-and-jonas-dulay).

Comment: above solution will not work when option texts are not in increment order.

Comment: @JonasDulay I hope it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<input type="number" name="quant" id="quant" />
<select name="shipment" disable>
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="100"> 100 per 1 item </option>
  <option value="150"> 150 per 4 item </option>
  <option value="150"> 150 per 5 item </option> 
  <option value="150"> 150 per 2 item </option>
  <option value="150"> 150 per 3 item </option>
</select>
```

JavaScript

```
   document.getElementById('quant').addEventListener("change", function(){
      multiply(this.form.elements.price.value,this.form.elements.quant.value);
      var value = parseInt(this.value, 10),
          selectEle = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0],
          options = selectEle.options,
          selectedNum = 0;
      for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        //checking the exact string with spaces (" " + value + " ")
        if(options[i].textContent.indexOf(" " + value + " ") > -1) {
            selectedNum = i;
        }
     }
     selectEle.selectedIndex = selectedNum ? selectedNum : 0;   
}, false);
```

Comment: when i choose 10 which is not on the select option field .. the select field must be null... the problem is that it does not change

Comment: now the problem is that my total price is not working anymore

Comment: just use your multiply function in this event block. check update

Comment: this is my multiply function dont know how to put it

Comment: <script>
function multiply(one, two,three) {
  if(one && two && three){
   
    this.form.elements.answer.value = one * two + +three;

  } else {
    this.style.color='red';
  }
}
</script>

Comment: you are passing two param when calling this function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102899/discussion-between-jonas-dulay-and-kp-singh).

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#quant').keyup(function() {
    var text = $(this).val();
    var select = $('select[name="shipment"]');
    var option = select.find(':contains(' + text + ')');
    if (option.length) {
      select.val(option.attr('value'));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" name="quant" id="quant" />
<select name="shipment" disable>
 <option value="100"> 100 per 1 item </option>
 <option value="150"> 150 per 2 item </option>
</select>
```

Sorry, don't know vanilla js solution.

Comment: I guess **JQuery** is not what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

**An alternative**

Create one attribute `data-quantity` in `<option>` tag. Give 1,2,3... value to it. And, in `<script>`, use `change()` or `keyup()` function.

```
<select name="shipment" id='selectbox'>
    <option value="100" data-quantity="1"> 100 per 1 item </option>
    <option value="150" data-quantity="2"> 150 per 2 item </option> 
</select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.quantity').change(function(){
            var quant= $('.quantity').val();
            $("#selectbox").find("option[data-quantity=" + quant + "]").attr('selected', 'selected').siblings().removeAttr('selected');
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: when i choose 4 which is not on the select option field it the select field must be null... the problem is that it does not change

Comment: There's a bug ... if i put 10 in the first no select value shows. but when i choose 1 then select value shows then change the value of quant again into 10 the select value is not changing to null